# Images taken from iphone getting rotated when I used it inside image tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iphone

Windows is showing me correct image and thumbnail is also currect as orientation of image but when I put source in image tag, it does get rotate.

Attaching image with this [image]

```
<html>
<body>
<img id="image1" src="C:\Users\admin\Desktop\636727412560304300.png" style="height: 500px;" >
</body>
```

Comment: Maybe the image is broken? Create a new image of it by doing a screenshot and replace the original one

Comment: Have you tried a different picture tool to view the image?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is a hardware issue, not a code problem. https://www.macworld.com/article/3065974/photography/how-to-solve-incorrect-photo-rotation-after-sync-or-upload.html
Had similar issues before.